# Server 2012r2 VPN DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, windows-server-2012, remote-access

Have an issue where  onsite clients cannot resolve VPNusers.  but VPN users can resolve onsite machines.

example.

- USER! uses LAPTOP1
- USER1 connects to VPN gets internal IP address of 10.243.0.200
- USER1 pings SERVER1 - resolve to ip and gets reply
- USER1 RDP into SERVER1 (inside VPN)
- USER1 pings LAPTOP1 from SERVER1 resolves to ip address last assigned by DHCP (10.243.0.139) ping fails
- USER1 pings 10.243.0.200 from SERVER1 gets reply.

Running Server 2012r2 It is a domain controller, DNS and VPN server.  VPN is just configured with basic default settings.

All VPN users have static IP setup in AD.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Are you using DHCP to assign the ip address for the VPN clients or are you using a static pool configured in the VPN server properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, ensure that your clients are configured to use the correct DNS server. Secondly, you must ensure that your VPN clients are registering with your DNS server;

Go to Network Settings for the VPN connection > TCP/IPv4 > Properties > Advanced > DNS > Tick "Register this connection's address in DNS".

Comment: Thanks, was already getting all dns information from the dns server.  Ticking the register box has worked. Is there a way to force this to happen from the server side?

Comment: Well that depends on how you're assigning an IP address to the VPN clients. You mention that it's static - except you also say that it's "setup in AD" - do you mean to say you have configured static reservations via DHCP? If so, then you should configure this under the VPN address pool. Go to the DHCP tool > Right click on the scope > click properties > click DNS > Check "Enable DNS dynamic updates".